# What are the possibilities for reverse engineering GraphQL API to batch fetch information?

Tags: python, graphql, screen-scraping

I’m working on a hobby project that revolves around Reddit’s avatar NFTs. Our small community of weirdos is passionate about collecting and trading these things. As Reddit generally doesn't care to really announce new avatar releases or provide information about the in a convenient way, I've built a few tools myself to do so.

**Background:**
Currently, my script relies on scraping IPFS metadata to obtain `graphql_id`s, which include a Polygon contract address and token ID. With these IDs, my script queries the Reddit GraphQL API to get information about each avatar. However, this process is cumbersome and really inconvenient.

Here’s an example of how I make a request to the API after obtaining a bearer token:

```py
response = session.post(
    'https://gql.reddit.com/',
    headers={
        'Authorization': f'Bearer {token_v2}',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    json={
        'variables': {'ids': ['nft_eip155:137_29c67b34b2e3af1dbcb7ceb365009c2bcfc1e0bc_249']},
        'id': 'a328c83b436a'  # Operation ID associated with the GraphQL query
    }
)
```

**Objective:**
My thinking is that there almost has to be a better way to get this metadata without first scraping IPFS indexes for specific tokenIDs (the contracts I can however easily request and use). Could it be possible to create a request without using the tokenIDs to get the metadata? Or maybe request ranges of tokenIDs? I've tried to do these things but haven't been successful. My current method is essentially copied based on what I see works by looking at the requests made in the Chrome network tab.

**Things I'd appreciate help/advice with:**

1. **Batch Query Support:** Can the Reddit GraphQL API provide avatars listing or accommodate queries for multiple avatars by expanding token IDs range?
2. **Efficient Retrieval Method:** Is there a structured approach, possibly using introspection or a different endpoint, that allows for batch fetching of avatar metadata without resorting to a brute-force method over potential `graphql_id`s?
3. **GraphQL Query Crafting:** How can I construct a GraphQL query to fetch multiple avatars or a full list without prior knowledge of specific `graphql_id`s?
4. **Analyzing GraphQL Endpoints:** Could you suggest tools that aid in analyzing GraphQL endpoint interactions between the client and server to unlock batch fetching capabilities?

**Additional Context:**

I am really new to GraphQL and programming as a whole, learning through a lot of trial and error as I go. While I've started to grasp the basics of handling the Reddit API, I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction to find better ways to do this.

I have tried changing the kinds of requests made to the API, but without success. Primarily due to my lack of experience I just don't seem to be able to really explore the API and I'm rather confused by a lot of the technicalities behind it like how introspection works etc.

I appreciate any assistance or insights that you can provide.